# Proving that a symmetric tridiagonal matrix is positive definite

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, symmetric-matrices, positive-definite, tridiagonal-matrices

How to prove that the square and symmetric matrix below is positive definite?

$$A = \begin{bmatrix} 
    81 & -40 &  \\
    -40 & 101 & -40 &  \\
    0 & -40 & 101 & -40 &  \\
    0 & 0 & -40 & 101 & -40 \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & 101& -40\\
     \dots & \dots  & \dots & \dots & \dots & \dots & -40 & 20
    \end{bmatrix}$$

I am self-studying linear algebra, and I wonder if I could prove this to be positive definite without using advanced theorems like the Gershgorin and Sylvester's criterion. What I know is, for a matrix to be positive definite, all eigenvalues must be positive or there is a vector $x$ such that $x^T Ax > 0$, where $x^T$ refers to the transposition of $x$. If I replace $-40$ by $0$, then $A$ is indeed positive definite since the diagonal entries are all positive. How could I continue this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $100 = 80 + 20$ and $\sqrt{80} \cdot \sqrt{20} = 40$. We have

$$
\begin{aligned}
x^{\mathsf{T}} A x &= 81 x_1^2 + 20 x_n^2 + 101 \sum_{1 < i < n} x_i^2 - 80 \sum x_i x_{i + 1} \\
&= \sum (\sqrt{80} x_i - \sqrt{20} x_{i + 1})^2 + \sum_{1 \le i < n} x_i^2 \\
&\ge 0 \text{.}
\end{aligned}
$$

And if the RHS $= 0$, then $x_i = 0$ for all $i \in [1, n - 1]$ and hence $x_n$, too.